# How to Allow Users To Drag Files Out of Cocoa App

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard

I am working on a macOS application that involves creating a folder in a temporary directory.

How can I allow users to drag a folder icon off of the Cocoa app and onto their desktop (or into Finder and other apps) so that dropping it will actually paste the folder created by the app?

I have so far been able to write the finished folder that I want to save to a temporary directory. How do I place a folder icon on the application that can be dragged into the Finder? Thanks!

The complete code I'm currently using is this:

```
    class draggableFolder: NSImageView {
    override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        let pasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
       // pasteboardItem.availableType(from: [NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
        pasteboardItem.setDataProvider(self, forTypes: [kUTTypeURL as NSPasteboard.PasteboardType])
        let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: pasteboardItem)
        draggingItem.setDraggingFrame(self.bounds, contents:self.image)

        beginDraggingSession(with: [draggingItem], event: theEvent, source: self as NSDraggingSource)
    }


}

extension draggableFolder: NSDraggingSource {
    func draggingSession(_ session: NSDraggingSession, sourceOperationMaskFor context: NSDraggingContext) -> NSDragOperation {
        return NSDragOperation.generic
    }
}

extension draggableFolder: NSPasteboardItemDataProvider {
    func pasteboard(_ pasteboard: NSPasteboard?, item: NSPasteboardItem, provideDataForType type:
        NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) {
        print("dataprovider")
        if let pasteboard = pasteboard, type.rawValue == String(describing: kUTTypeURL) {
           let folder = currentIconsetURL
            print("dataprovider2")
            print(NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: currentIconsetURL))
            pasteboard.clearContents()
            pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileNameType(forPathExtension: "appiconset")], owner: nil)
            pasteboard.writeObjects([(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: currentIconsetURL).absoluteURL as NSURL) as NSPasteboardWriting])


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question, how to start a drag, how to create a folder or something else? Tell us what you've done so far.

Comment: Thank you@Willeke. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Willeke I have updated the question to contain the code I'm using.

Comment: Take a look at `NSFilePromiseProvider`, the documentation is missing but you can read about it in [AppKit Release Notes (macOS 10.12 and Earlier)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/), Dragging File Promise Source.

Comment: Thanks @willeke. I've read that NSFilePromiseProvider is used when you need to create a file that doesn't exist on the filesystem. Is that correct? I the I want to appear in Finer already exists in my app's temporary directory, and I want the user to be able to move it elsewhere.

Comment: You can "create" a file by moving it from the temporary directory.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, the drag and drop guide Apple has is based entirely on the old deprecated API: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html

The rough outline for what you're asking, using the modern API is:

- You need something (ex, your view) to implement the `NSDraggingSource` protocol to return that it supports the Copy operation only (`draggingSession(_:sourceOperationMaskFor:)`).
- From within `mouseDown` (with a tracking loop) or `mouseDragged`, once the user's drag has moved a certain distance from its original location (3 or 4 points is all), then you should start a dragging session (`NSView beginDraggingSession`)
- The session should contain one `NSDraggingItem` where you pass in the URL for the folder (as an `NSURL`, not a Swift `URL`, because only the former conforms to `NSPasteboardWriter`).

Comment: Thank you @seth. I'm running into the issue where the dragged file just writes the folder's path to a clipping file. The issue seems to be in the file type. I'm using `kUTTypeFolder` currently. Is this correct?

Comment: Where are you using that UTI? In the most basic form, you'd literally just hand over the URL and nothing else: `let draggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: fileURL as NSURL); ...; beginDraggingSession(with: [draggingItem], event: currentEvent, source: self)`

Comment: If I use the code in the above comment, I cannot run seem to specify the data provider. How would I do this? I suspect this is the issue because when I attempt to drag the folder onto the desktop a grey prohibitory sign appears on the folder image.

Comment: Just as an update, I nearly got everything working. The only issue is that when I drag the file to the desktop, the file isn't written to the location..

Comment: Hi @Jake3231, did you get a solution for dragging file outside the cocoa app? If yes, can you please share the solution?